# 2500 people have a car insurance there are 1500 women and 1000 men. Estimate probability that in the next year there will be at least 25 car accidents

Tags: probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

> 2500 people have a car insurance, there are 1500 women, and 1000 men. Probability that a woman does a car accident is 1%. Probability that a man does a car accident is 1.5%.

exercise asks to estimate probability that in the next year there will be at least 25 car accidents.

here's what I've done:

I've used central limit theorem, and I have to find $P(X \geq25)$, which is equal to $$P(N(0, 1)\geq \frac{(365)-(25*365)}{\sqrt(365*25)})$$

now, I've rewritten it as $$1-\phi(-91.7839)$$

and I highly doubt this result is correct. So I've read the text again,

- 25 car accidents is the required data in the next year.
- of course, 365 is the total amount of days of the year.

in central limit theorem formula there's no space for probabilities (i.e P(woman), and P(man)), therefore these data are useless for the sake of central limit theorem.

I think I have to take into account the total number of people who have the car insurance. But I don't think it's correct, because the average and the variance of a normal distribution are: $$average = 365 * 25, \space variance = 365 * 25 $$

whenever I have an exercise like this, I have to compute the average and the variance in the same way. [because of theory. 365 is the number of events, and I have to multiply it by the average of the previous random variable]

I have no clue.

Comment: The car accident probabilities and the number of people are provided to calculate the average number of accidents.

Comment: @peterwhy but it's not De Moivre-Laplace theorem. I can't compute average with n*p, this is valid only for binomial approximation and for poisson approximation

Comment: I would calculate the average number of accidents and the standard deviation in the number of accidents. You can then use a Gaussian model and check what the probability is of 25 or more accidents.

Comment: Let $W\sim \text{Binomial}(1500,0.01)$ be the number of car accidents from women and $M\sim \text{Binomial}(1000,0.015)$ the number of car accidents from men.

From CLT we have $W$ is approximately $\mathcal{N}\left(15,\frac{297}{20}\right)$ and $M$ is approximately $\mathcal{N}\left(15,\frac{591}{40}\right)$. Assuming $W$ and $M$ are independent, we can say $W+M$ is approximately $\mathcal{N}\left(30,\frac{237}{8}\right)$.

Can you finish?

Comment: I'm guessing that 365 shouldn't have a place in your answer. I think the 1% of woman having an accident means 1% have an accident over the year.

Comment: I've tried, and this is the result. $P(N(0, 1)\geq \frac{(365)-(25*30)}{\sqrt(25*14.79)})$

Comment: @MatthewH. the right hand side of the inequality is equal to -20

Comment: Did you read my comment? The number of accidents made by the $1500$ women is a random variable that possesses a binomial distribution which can be approximated with a normal distribution. The same can be done with the men. I'm not sure where you're getting your figures from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are versions of CLT that does not require identically distributed random variables. See, e.g, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Lyapunov_CLT) and http://personal.psu.edu/drh20/asymp/fall2002/lectures/ln04.pdf.

Let $W_i$, $i = 1,\dots,1500$ be a random variable such that $P(W_i = 0) = 0.01$ and $P(W_i = 0) = 0.99$. Similarly, let $M_j$, $j = 1,\dots,1000$ be such that $P(M_j = 1) = 0.015$ and $P(M_j = 0) = 0.985$. Then you need to calculate
$$
P\left(\sum_i W_i + \sum_j M_i \ge 25\right).
$$
Rewriting the event in the form
$$
P\left(\frac{\sum_i (W_i - 0.01) + \sum_j (M_j - 0.015)}{\sqrt{1500 \cdot 0.01 \cdot 0.99 + 1000 \cdot 0.015 \cdot 0.985}} \ge \frac{-5}{\sqrt{29.625}} \right) = P\left(\mathcal{N}(0,1) \ge \frac{-5}{\sqrt{29.625}} \right) = 0.82098\dots,
$$
which is more or less the same answer as this obtained by the method of @Matthew H.

Comment: thanks, I have only a question, where does this "-5" come from?

Comment: @GabrielBurzacchini You just need to transform $\sum W_i + \sum M_j \ge 25$. When you subtract $1500 \cdot 0.01 + 1000 \cdot 0.015 = 30$ from both sides, then you get $\sum (W_i - 0.01) + \sum (M_j - 0.015) \ge -5$.